# How to count number of matches between two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

How to count number of matches between two columns in Excel?

For example if we have:

```
1 1
2 1 
3 2
4 4
5 3
```

I need to get either a column like this:

1
0
0
1
0

and then I can sum the ones in there to get the count of matches.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1: IF

```
=IF(A1=B1;1;0)
```

This formula will put 1 in the cell if A1 = B1, and 0 otherwise.

### Option 2: COUNTIF

Write `=A1=B1` in C1, etc., in the column cells. This will fill the C column with `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

At the bottom of that column, add a cell `=COUNTIF(C1:C100;TRUE)` so that you count the cells between C1 and C100 which have value `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the TechRepublic article [Use COUNTIFS() to compare two data sets in Excel](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-countifs-to-compare-two-data-sets-in-excel/) of use.  See also [Microsoft's documentation on `countifs()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx).

Comment: Although this might help OP, *link only* answers are discouraged since the link may become invalid after some time. Also, it is more suited as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an UI element for commenting a post directly.  Maybe I don't have the privilege yet.

Comment: You're right... I see now that you need at least 50 rep to comment on other peoples post.